# Mediaroutebutton Inflate

Tags: java, android

I want to inflate mediaroutebutton in service , I have exoplayer in my service layout, permission granted draw overlay, override exoplayer control view, when I add mediaroutebutton in exoplayer control view, layout inflate exception occur

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0
    at android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils.calculateContrast(ColorUtils.java:161)
    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getControllerColor(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:164)
    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getRouterThemeId(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:257)
    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedButtonContext(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:94)
    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:125)
    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:121)
```

mediaroutebutton background is transparent

Comment: Did you try not make it transparent/translucent?

Comment: Tenten Ponce try it also try Robolectric but not work for me